# passing local script variables to viml functions

Tags: functions, variables

If I run this code:

```
let s:user_config=fnamemodify('user.vim', ':p')
echom s:user_config
if filereadable("s:user_config")
  echom 'this is true'
else
  echom 'this is false'
endif
```

the result will be:

```
/root/vim_test/user.vim
this is false
```

Even though there is a valid file at the path.

Why this is happening? Am I passing the variables wrongly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing whether the file literally named "s:user_config" exists. Try this instead:

```
if filereadable(s:user_config)
```